# How can validate form duplicate name in the Name Field using Redux form?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, redux-form-validators

```
 import React from 'react'
 import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

 const required = value => value ? undefined : 'Required'

 const renderField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } })=> (
                 <div>
                    <label>{label}</label>
                 <div>
                     <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type}/>

                     {touched && ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||  
                     (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
                      </div>
                     </div>
                 )

             const FieldLevelValidationForm = (props) => {
             const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props
           return (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                  <Field name="username" type="text"
                   component={renderField} label="Username"
                   validate={[ required, maxLength15 ]}
                   />
                  <div>
                 <button type="submit" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
                 <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting}    
                    onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
                 </div>
                 </form>
                  )
               }

         export default reduxForm({form: 'fieldLevelValidation'})                   
           (FieldLevelValidationForm)
```

The current implementation is missing the duplicate username entry input validation.
I would like to know how can I define the logic to validate the duplicate username field input in the form?

Comment: This isn't clear enough to me. You need to add more code. What have you tried?

Comment: Please check the code,I have edited

Comment: Check out the example in the `redux-form` docs, they do a username validation example here: https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/asyncvalidation/ under asyncValidate.js

Comment: I already checked the documentations. It seems we can do it using asyncValidate but how can dispatch the actions we need to pass the username. For example, ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo'] those name should ´be checked from the server side...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `asyncValidate` in `reduxForm` [here](https://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/asyncvalidation/). In addition you should use dispatch in your validation. You should do it same as bellow:

```
const asyncValidate = (values, dispatch) => {
  //using dispatch here
}
```

Comment: export const asyncValidate = values =>
  service.getItems().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res.includes(values.name)) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-throw-literal
      throw { name: 'The cost structure name needs to be unique' };
    }
  });
I have been trying this but seems not working...

Comment: You should pass your validation to your Form too, So you should doo this 
``` 
 export default reduxForm({form: 'fieldLevelValidation', validate: asyncValidate})                   
           (FieldLevelValidationForm)
```
.If it's not working could you write the both validation and form because then I could check it?

Comment: hum I did this as well but that was not the problems. The problems happened due to the API request inside the promises in asyncValidate function which doesn't pass the errors to the form itself.